# SSD compatibility issues?

Tags: ssd, compatibility

I'm thinking of buying this PC http://velocitymicro.com/wizard.php?iid=186 along with a SSD drive from newegg. I'm worried that my new SSD drive won't be compatible with motherboards so I'm thinking maybe i should spend a premium by buying an Intel SSD G2 drive for maximum compatbility. I don't even know if Intel is more/less compatible with other motherboards but i'm assuming it is more.

The question is, should I be worried be about compatibility? Do you think I'll be okay by buying an SSD from OCZ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any standard SATA based SSD will work with any SATA based socket.

If the computer takes SATA drives, you should have no problem using SSD sata drives.

If however the SATA drive is a PCI Express one, you may have problems - but I haven't seen any of those in a while.

Comment: This is, unfortunately, incorrect.  See for example, http://www.anandtech.com/mac/showdoc.aspx?i=3672&p=5

Comment: ok... My answer - with the exception of the mac book in that article! Thanks, +1

Comment: True, sorry if sometimes people forget about Mac and linux compatibility ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should buy also an 2.5" to 3.5" adapter since most SSDs are 2.5" and desktop cases don't provide a 2.5" mount

Answer (score 0):

I recently bought an OCZ Agility drive.  I cloned my existing SATA hard drive to it and then booted off the SSD. All worked fine.  An SSD drive is drop-in compatible with typical SATA hard drives.

The only issue is that SSD drives are 2.5" (laptop size) and desktop hard drives are 3.5" so you may have to buy an adapter to mount the drive.

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues with sata SSD's before. Toshiba comes to mind. My guess is that some of the older stuff will also have issues.  Essentially 95% compatibility across the board. There will always be that drive that will only work on certain computers though.